# Is it possible to dynamically populate choices in one field of a question, based on answers in another field of the same question?

Tags: docassemble

So for example, is something like this possible, perhaps using ajax calls, so that the latter field populates properly?

```
question: |
  Where do you live?
fields:
 - Country: country
  input type: combobox
  code: countries_list()
 - State: state
  input type: combobox
  code: states_list(country)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docassemble customization is based around server-side Python, not client-side JavaScript, so there is no built-in system for creating screens like this. The standard way to do this in Docassemble would be to have two `question`s, one for the country and one for the state, which would be on separate screens. The code for that would be simple.

There is [an example in the documentation](https://docassemble.org/docs/background.html#target) that uses `check in` along with `background_response('refresh')` to regenerate the screen when the value of an input element changes. This works ok if there are just two fields on the screen; otherwise you need to adjust for the fact that refreshing the screen will wipe out the user's answers to the other fields.

Refreshing the screen is overkill just to update the values in a `<select>`. Another way you could accomplish this is to write a jQuery event handler that listens for a `change` on the country field and uses [`action_call()`](https://docassemble.org/docs/functions.html#js_url_action_call) to retrieve a list of states from Python. (It would be best to avoid using the "combobox" and use `<select>` instead, because the "combobox" comes from an add-on package and it doesn't act the same way as a native input element.) The action in Python would use [`json_response()`](https://docassemble.org/docs/functions.html#json_response) to return the list of states as a JSON object, and your JavaScript callback function would use that to substitute a new set of `<option>` elements inside the `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses the "overkill" method:

```
---
imports:
  - pycountry
---
code: |
  default_country_code = "US"
---
code: |
    def safe_subdivision_type(country_code):
        try:
            return subdivision_type(country_code)
        except:
            return None
---
event: update_state_list
code: |
  if action_argument('default_country_code') and action_argument('default_country_code') != default_country_code:          
    default_country_code = action_argument('default_country_code')
    background_response('refresh')
  background_response()    
---
id: dependency question
question: |
  Select a country and state
fields:
  - Default country (for address fields): default_country_code
    code: |
      countries_list()
    default: ${ default_country_code }
  - Default ${ safe_subdivision_type(default_country_code) if safe_subdivision_type(default_country_code) else 'State/Province'}: state
    code: |
        states_list(country_code=default_country_code) if pycountry.subdivisions.get(country_code=default_country_code) else ()
    default: ${ "MA" if default_country_code == 'US' else '' }
    required: False
check in: update_state_list
```

(This comes from the [AssemblyLine Weaver](https://github.com/SuffolkLITLab/docassemble-ALWeaver/blob/7fe5ae5c02ed39c1b254b94fce733fec724ec2a8/docassemble/ALWeaver/data/questions/assembly_line.yml#L541) project)